# Adding a 3rd column for links to a Google DataTable in order to draw a ChartWrapper

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using Google ColumnChart and I want to add links on columns. But on the other hand, I want to use a NumberRangeFilter on this chart. I have managed to do both things separately, but I can't bring them together on the chart. The reason seems to be the 3rd column that I add for links in the DataTable, that causes an error in the application :

> One or more participants failed to draw()
>
> All series on a given axis must be of the same data type

Here is what I have tried :

1. Add a link on columns :

   ```
   // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
   google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'controls'] });

   // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {

   // DataTable with 3 columns, and the 2nd is for links
   var dataStats = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Name of X axis', 'link', 'Name of Y axis'],
       // Use of PHP variables
       {% if stats is defined and stats is not null %}
           {% for stat in stats %}
               ['{{ stat['id'] }}', '{{ path('the_path', {'id': stat['id']}) }}', {{ stat['COUNT(*)'] }}],
           {% endfor %}
       {% else %}
           ['0', '{{ path('other_path') }}', 0],
       {% endif %}
   ]);

   // Options for the DataTable
   var optionsStats = { 
   // ...
   };

   // DataView
   var viewStats = new google.visualization.DataView(dataStats);
   viewStats.setColumns([0, 2]);

   // Draw the chart
   var chartStats = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('stats_div'));
   chartStats.draw(viewStats, optionsStats);

   //Listener on the chart
   function selectColumn() {
       window.location = dataStats.getValue(chartStats.getSelection()[0]['row'], 1);
   }
   google.visualization.events.addListener(chartStats, 'select', selectColumn);
   ```

   It makes all columns clickable and gives a customized appearance.
2. Add a filter to print only some datas :

   ```
   //Dashboard
   var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div')); 

   //Chart range filter
   var rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
       'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
       'containerId': 'control_div',
       'options': {
           'filterColumnIndex': 1 // Should be set to 2 if there is a column 
                                  // for links in the DataTable, to filter values of Y axis
        }
   });

   // The chart is now a ChartWrapper to fit in the dashboard
   var chartStats = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
      'containerId': 'stats_div'
   });

   // Establish dependencies
   dashboard.bind(rangeFilter, chartStats);

   // Draw the dashboard
   dashboard.draw(dataStats);
   ```

Note that there are no more options on the ChartWrapper because it seems not to work the same as ColumnChart.

Finally, how could I add a column for links in the DataTable and add a range filter at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you can use the same chart options on the wrapper,
just assign to the wrapper's options property

you can also place a view, directly on the wrapper

to assign your select event, first listen for the wrapper's ready event,
then assign the select event on the chart by using --> `wrapper.getChart()`

see following snippet...

```
//Dashboard
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

//Chart range filter
var rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
  containerId: 'control_div',
  options: {
    filterColumnIndex: 2
   }
});

// The chart is now a ChartWrapper to fit in the dashboard
var chartStats = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'ColumnChart',
  containerId: 'stats_div',
  options: optionsStats,
  view: {
    columns: [0, 2]
  }
});

function selectColumn() {
  window.location = dataStats.getValue(chartStats.getSelection()[0]['row'], 1);
}

google.visualization.events.addListener(chartStats, 'ready', function () {
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chartStats.getChart(), 'select', selectColumn);
});

// Establish dependencies
dashboard.bind(rangeFilter, chartStats);

// Draw the dashboard
dashboard.draw(dataStats);
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps but it doesn't work totally : the visual is fine, the filter works but the redirection doesn't when I click on a column... The event seems to be taken in account because I can't select any other column when I click on one, but it doesn't go on the webpage. I have verified, it works if I remove the modifications, so it doesn't come from the path I put in the DataTable.

Comment: Finally, it worked for me when I put getChart() in selectColumn function : dataStats.getValue(chartsStats.getChart().getSelection()...) and just let chartStats in addListener().